# Poisson Expectation of a price asset

Tags: markov-process, poisson-distribution

If I have that the price of some asset is given by:

$S(t)=s \times exp{(\alpha-\lambda \sigma)t} (\sigma + 1)^{N(t)}, t \ge 0$

where $s=S(0)>0, \alpha>0, \sigma > -1$ and $\lambda > 0$ are constants, and {$N(t) : t \ge 0$} is a Poisson process with intensity $\lambda$.

I'm supposed to Find $E[e^{-\alpha t} S(t)]$. So I tried to find this expectation by calculating:

$$
\mbox{E}(e^{-\alpha t} S(t)) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{\alpha t}s \times exp{(\alpha-\lambda \sigma)t} (\sigma + 1)^{N(t)}\:dt
$$

Now I'm stuck as I am drawing a blank how to combine any terms or how to integrate this.  Did I even set this up correctly, and is this integrable?  Thanks for any all help

Comment: Did you mean $\times$ instead of $*$ ?

Comment: Yes, I'll edit it quickly, thanks

Comment: I am confused by notation is it $$\mathrm{e}^{(\alpha-\lambda \sigma)t}$$ or $$\mathrm{e}^{(\alpha-\lambda \sigma)}t$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $N(t)$ is Poisson, which is discrete (its pdf is $\frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k}{k!}$), then you need summation and not integral:

$$\mbox{E}(e^{-\alpha t} S(t)) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} e^{-\alpha t}s  e^{(\alpha-\lambda \sigma)t} (\sigma + 1)^{k} \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t)^k}{k!} =\\= se^{-\lambda\sigma t}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda t}(\lambda t(\sigma+1))^k}{k!} = \\= se^{-\lambda\sigma t}e^{\lambda t(\sigma+1)}e^{-\lambda t(\sigma+1)}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda t(\sigma+1)}(\lambda t(\sigma+1))^k}{k!} = \\= se^{-\lambda\sigma t}e^{\lambda t}e^{-\lambda t(\sigma+1)} = \\ = se^{-2\lambda t\sigma},$$

since $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-\lambda t(\sigma+1)}(\lambda t(\sigma+1))^k}{k!}=1$$